# Designing a Calculator in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

I'm new in Java and I'm finding it hard to implement a GUI here unlike in Visual Basic.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class CalculatorGui extends JFrame{
    private static final int WIDTH = 250;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;

    private JTextField enterTextField;

    private JButton sevenB, eightB, nineB, divideB, fourB, fiveB, sixB, multiplyB, oneB, twoB, threeB, subtractB, zeroB, dotB, equalsB, addB;

    public CalculatorGui() {
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));

        enterTextField = new JTextField(30);

        sevenB = new JButton("7");
        eightB = new JButton("8");
        nineB = new JButton("9");
        divideB = new JButton("/");
        fourB = new JButton("4");
        fiveB = new JButton("5");
        sixB = new JButton("6");
        multiplyB = new JButton("*");
        oneB = new JButton("1");
        twoB = new JButton("2");
        threeB = new JButton("3");
        subtractB = new JButton("-");
        zeroB = new JButton("0");
        dotB = new JButton(".");
        equalsB = new JButton("=");
        addB = new JButton("+");

        /*JPanel dataPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        FlowLayout flowCenter = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        GridLayout aGrid = new GridLayout(4, 4);

        buttonPanel.setLayout(flowCenter);
        dataPanel.setLayout(aGrid);


        dataPanel.add(enterTextField);
        buttonPanel.add(sevenB);
        buttonPanel.add(eightB);
        buttonPanel.add(nineB);
        buttonPanel.add(divideB);
        buttonPanel.add(fourB);
        buttonPanel.add(fiveB);
        buttonPanel.add(sixB);
        buttonPanel.add(multiplyB);
        buttonPanel.add(oneB);
        buttonPanel.add(twoB);
        buttonPanel.add(threeB);
        buttonPanel.add(subtractB);
        buttonPanel.add(zeroB);
        buttonPanel.add(dotB);
        buttonPanel.add(equalsB);
        buttonPanel.add(addB);

        add(dataPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);*/

        //add(enterTextField);
        add(sevenB);
        add(eightB);
        add(nineB);
        add(divideB);
        add(fourB);
        add(fiveB);
        add(sixB);
        add(multiplyB);
        add(oneB);
        add(twoB);
        add(threeB);
        add(subtractB);
        add(zeroB);
        add(dotB);
        add(equalsB);
        add(addB);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CalculatorGui calcu = new CalculatorGui();

    }

}
```

It runs but I need to put a **text field right before those buttons** (numbers). The text field should **flow** and will not be enlarged when the window is maximized (unlike the 4x4 buttons). I've tried **JPanel** (see comments) but it outputs a horrible design. P

Comment: possible duplicate of [about layouts in simple calculator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824162/about-layouts-in-simple-calculator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, with some rules to follow while building GUI ([rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519)):
**Do not subclass AWT/Swing/X Components for application needs**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CalculatorGui {

    private static final int WIDTH = 250;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 250;
    private JTextField enterTextField;
    private JButton sevenB, eightB, nineB, divideB, fourB, fiveB, sixB, multiplyB, oneB, twoB, threeB, subtractB, zeroB, dotB, equalsB, addB;

    public CalculatorGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setTitle("Calculator");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));        
        enterTextField = new JTextField();       

        frame.add(enterTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        sevenB = new JButton("7");
        eightB = new JButton("8");
        nineB = new JButton("9");
        divideB = new JButton("/");
        fourB = new JButton("4");
        fiveB = new JButton("5");
        sixB = new JButton("6");
        multiplyB = new JButton("*");
        oneB = new JButton("1");
        twoB = new JButton("2");
        threeB = new JButton("3");
        subtractB = new JButton("-");
        zeroB = new JButton("0");
        dotB = new JButton(".");
        equalsB = new JButton("=");
        addB = new JButton("+");

        buttonPanel.add(sevenB);
        buttonPanel.add(eightB);
        buttonPanel.add(nineB);
        buttonPanel.add(divideB);
        buttonPanel.add(fourB);
        buttonPanel.add(fiveB);
        buttonPanel.add(sixB);
        buttonPanel.add(multiplyB);
        buttonPanel.add(oneB);
        buttonPanel.add(twoB);
        buttonPanel.add(threeB);
        buttonPanel.add(subtractB);
        buttonPanel.add(zeroB);
        buttonPanel.add(dotB);
        buttonPanel.add(equalsB);
        buttonPanel.add(addB);

        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculatorGui calcu = new CalculatorGui();
    }
}
```

I would suggest you to use [WindowsBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) after a good manual practice with some `layouts` and `components`

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I really appreciate your help. I'll work on WindowsBuilderPro as soon as I master Java. :) Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are from Visual Basic you will be into habits of drag and drop, then why leave it when you can do it in Java too.

Use WindowsBuilder Pro, now free from Google, and use the Group Layout to design your application present in it. Group Layout was developed by the NetBeans team back in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I am new, but i have a code for designing a calculator using AWT.It is only a sample.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    public class Calculator extends Frame
    {
    public Calculator(String s)
    {
        String buttonString = "789/456*123-0.=+";
        for (int i = 0, x=0,y=50; i 

              Button b = new Button(buttonString.substring(i, i + 1));
              b.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
              add(b);
              if((i+1)%4==0)
              {
                  x=0;
                  y+=50;
              }
              else
              {
                  x=x+50;
              }
    }
    TextField txtField=new TextField("0");
    txtField.setBounds(0,0, 200, 30);
    add(txtField);
    setSize(200,255);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new Calculator("Calculator");
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### custom calculator

GUI is frame custom...

```
public class Calculator implements ActionListener
{

final static Point point = new Point();
JFrame frame;
JButton one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zone,cancel,clear,cancel1,sub,add,equal,dot,mult,div,adsub,baket,up;
JPanel top,top1,top2,down,down1,down2,history;
JLabel name,images;
//JTextField text1,text2;
ImageIcon up1,up2;
JTextPane text1;
JScrollPane pane;
ScriptEngine engine;
Border em;
boolean endwith1;
int numbcount=1,opercount=1,numbcount1=1;
boolean operaffer=true;
int lensold;
boolean baketsub=true;
boolean dotcheck=false;
boolean baketcheck=true;
int baketcount=0;
int baketcount1=1;
boolean check;
boolean check1;
SimpleAttributeSet attrib;

public Calculator()
{
    frame = new JFrame();

    engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");

    name = new JLabel(" Calculator");
    name.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    name.setFont(new FontUIResource("Franklin Gothic Medium", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    one = new JButton("1");
    one.addActionListener(this);
    one.setFocusPainted(false);
    one.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    one.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    one.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    one.setFont(new FontUIResource("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    two = new JButton("2");
    two.addActionListener(this);
    two.setFocusPainted(false);
    two.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    two.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    two.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    two.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    three = new JButton("3");
    three.addActionListener(this);
    three.setFocusPainted(false);
    three.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    three.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    three.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    three.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    four = new JButton("4");
    four.addActionListener(this);
    four.setFocusPainted(false);
    four.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    four.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    four.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    four.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    five = new JButton("5");
    five.addActionListener(this);
    five.setFocusPainted(false);
    five.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    five.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    five.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    five.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    six = new JButton("6");
    six.addActionListener(this);
    six.setFocusPainted(false);
    six.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    six.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    six.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    six.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    seven = new JButton("7");
    seven.addActionListener(this);
    seven.setFocusPainted(false);
    seven.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    seven.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    seven.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    seven.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    eight = new JButton("8");
    eight.addActionListener(this);
    eight.setFocusPainted(false);
    eight.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    eight.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    eight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    eight.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    nine = new JButton("9");
    nine.addActionListener(this);
    nine.setFocusPainted(false);
    nine.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    nine.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    nine.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    nine.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    zone = new JButton("0");
    zone.addActionListener(this);
    zone.setFocusPainted(false);
    zone.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    zone.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    zone.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    zone.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    cancel = new JButton("x");
    cancel.addActionListener(this);
    cancel.setFocusPainted(false);
    cancel.setBackground(new Color(48, 174, 184));
    cancel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    cancel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(6,6,6,6));
    cancel.setFont(new Font("OCR-A BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    cancel1 = new JButton("X");
    cancel1.addActionListener(this);
    cancel1.setFocusPainted(false);
    cancel1.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    cancel1.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
    cancel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    cancel1.setFont(new Font("OCR-A BT", Font.BOLD, 25));

    clear = new JButton("C");
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    clear.setFocusPainted(false);
    clear.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    clear.setForeground(new Color(49, 166, 216));
    clear.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    clear.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.BOLD,35));

    sub = new JButton("-");
    sub.addActionListener(this);
    sub.setFocusPainted(false);
    sub.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    sub.setForeground(new Color(49, 166, 216));
    sub.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    sub.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 35));

    add = new JButton("+");
    add.addActionListener(this);
    add.setFocusPainted(false);
    add.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    add.setForeground(new Color(49, 166, 216));
    add.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    add.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 35));

    mult = new JButton("*");
    mult.addActionListener(this);
    mult.setFocusPainted(false);
    mult.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    mult.setForeground(new Color(49, 166, 216));
    mult.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    mult.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 35));

    div = new JButton("/");
    div.addActionListener(this);
    div.setFocusPainted(false);
    div.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    div.setForeground(new Color(49, 166, 216));
    div.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    div.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 30));

    equal = new JButton("=");
    equal.addActionListener(this);
    equal.setFocusPainted(false);
    equal.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    equal.setForeground(new Color(0, 153, 0));
    equal.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    equal.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.BOLD, 35));

    dot = new JButton(".");
    dot.addActionListener(this);
    dot.setFocusPainted(false);
    dot.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    dot.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    dot.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    dot.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    adsub = new JButton("+/-");
    adsub.addActionListener(this);
    adsub.setFocusPainted(false);
    adsub.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    adsub.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    adsub.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    adsub.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    baket = new JButton("()");
    baket.addActionListener(this);
    baket.setFocusPainted(false);
    baket.setBackground(new Color(250, 250, 250));
    baket.setForeground(new Color(49, 166, 216));
    baket.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 240, 240),1));
    baket.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 25));

    //text1 = new JTextField();
    //text1.setColumns(10);
    //text1.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT",Font.PLAIN, 35));
    //text1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 7, 4, 7));
    //text1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
    //text1.setCaretColor(new Color(49, 166, 216));



    attrib  = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    StyleConstants.setAlignment(attrib, StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrib, 30);
    text1 = new JTextPane();
    text1.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
    text1.setParagraphAttributes(attrib, true);
    text1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 7, 4, 7));
    text1.setCaretColor(new Color(49, 166, 216));
    text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 130));
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(text1);
    scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 5));
    scrollpane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUI(new ScrollLookandFeel());
    em = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0);
    scrollpane.setBorder(em);
    UIManager.put("ScrollBarUI", "My.package.ScrollLookandFeel");


    //text2 = new JTextField();z
    //text2.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT",Font.PLAIN, 35));
    // text2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 7, 4, 7));
    // text2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    // text2.setForeground(new Color(0, 153, 0));
    // text2.setCaretColor(new Color(49, 166, 216));

    up2 = new ImageIcon(CreateImage("/project/1467651440_calculator.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    images = new JLabel(up2);
    images.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(48, 174, 184),4));

    top = new JPanel();
    top1 = new JPanel();
    top1.setSize(200,400);
    top1.setBackground(new Color(48, 174, 184));
    top1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    top1.add(images,BorderLayout.WEST);
    top1.add(name,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    top1.add(cancel,BorderLayout.EAST);

    top2 = new JPanel();
    top2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    top2.add(scrollpane,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   //top2.add(text2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    top.add(top1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    top.add(top2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    down = new JPanel();
    down.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    up1 = new ImageIcon(CreateImage("/project/1467658414_arrow-down-01_1.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(15, 15, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    up = new JButton();
    up.setIcon(up1);
    up.setFocusPainted(false);
    up.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
    up.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    up.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(187, 197, 201),0));
    up.setFont(new Font("OCR-B 10 BT", Font.PLAIN, 15));

    down1 = new JPanel();
    down1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    down1.add(up);

    down2 = new JPanel();
    down2.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
    down2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
    down2.add(clear);
    down2.add(div);
    down2.add(mult);
    down2.add(cancel1);
    down2.add(seven);
    down2.add(eight);
    down2.add(nine);
    down2.add(sub);
    down2.add(four);
    down2.add(five);
    down2.add(six);
    down2.add(add);
    down2.add(one);
    down2.add(two);
    down2.add(three);
    down2.add(baket);
    down2.add(zone);
    down2.add(dot);
    down2.add(adsub);
    down2.add(equal);

    down.add(down1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    down.add(down2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.add(top,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(down,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(270,450);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setIconImage(CreateImage("/project/1467651440_calculator.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(60, 60, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            point.x = e.getX();
            point.y = e.getY();
        }
    });

    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
            Point p = frame.getLocation();
            frame.setLocation(p.x+e.getX()-point.x,p.y+e.getY()-point.y);
        }

    });
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private ImageIcon CreateImage(String path)
{
    return new ImageIcon(java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getClass().getResource(path));
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    switch(e.getActionCommand())
    {
        case "1":
            numberAction("1");
            break;
        case "2":
            numberAction("2");
            break;
        case "3":
            numberAction("3");
            break;
        case "4":
            numberAction("4");
            break;
        case "5":
            numberAction("5");
            break;
        case "6":
            numberAction("6");
            break;    
        case "7":
            numberAction("7");
            break;    
        case "8":
            numberAction("8");
            break;    
        case "9":
            numberAction("9");
            break;
        case "0":
            numberAction("0");
            break;
        case ".":
            dots(".");
            break;
        case "+":
            digitalAction("+");
            break;
        case "-":
            digitalAction("-");
            break; 
        case "*":
            digitalAction("*");
            break; 
        case "/":
            digitalAction("/");
            break;     
        case "=":
              total();
            break;    
        case "C":
              clear(); 
            break;
        case "X":
              cancel1(); 
            break;
        case "()":
            Baket();
            break;
        case "+/-":
            baketsub();
            break;
    }

    if(e.getSource()==cancel)
    {        
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
    }
}

private void clear() 
{
   numbcount=1;
   opercount=1;
   numbcount1=1;
   baketcount=0;
   baketcount1=1;
   baketcheck=true;
   baketsub=true;
   operaffer=true;
   text1.setText("");
}

private void digitalAction(String operation) 
{
    if(!text1.getText().equals(""))
    {    
        String txt1 = text1.getText();
        endwith1 = txt1.endsWith(operation);
        System.out.println("text "+endwith1);

        int len = txt1.length();
        String subs = txt1.substring(len-1);
        System.out.println(subs);

        if(endwith1==true)
        {

        }else
        {
            if(!subs.equals("+") && !subs.equals("-") && !subs.equals("/") && !subs.equals("*"))
            {    
                if(opercount<=5)
                {   
                    text1.setText(text1.getText()+operation);
                    opercount++;
                }

                String txt10  = text1.getText();
                boolean add1 = txt10.endsWith("+");
                boolean sub1 = txt10.endsWith("-");
                boolean mult1 = txt10.endsWith("*");
                boolean div1 = txt10.endsWith("/");

                if(true==add1 ||true==sub1 ||true==mult1 || true==div1 )
                {
                    operaffer=false;
                    numbcount1=1;
                }

            }else
            {
                String hide=text1.getText();
                text1.setText("");
                for(int J=0;J<hide.length()-1;J++)
                {    
                    text1.setText(text1.getText()+hide.charAt(J));
                }

                text1.setText(text1.getText()+operation);
            }    
        }
    }else
    {
        text1.setText("");
    }  
    baketcheck=true;
}

private void numberAction(String buttonNumber)
{    
    if(true==operaffer)
    {    
        String txt2 = text1.getText();
        boolean endwith2 = txt2.endsWith(")");

        if(true!=endwith2)
        {    
            if(!text1.getText().equals("0"))
            {  
                if(numbcount<=5)
                {   
                    text1.setText(text1.getText()+buttonNumber);
                    numbcount++;
                }
                dotcheck=true;
                baketsub=false;

                String txt3 = text1.getText();
                lensold = txt3.length();
                System.out.println("len"+lensold);
                check = txt3.contains(".");
                System.out.println(check); 
            }else
            {
                String hide=text1.getText();
                text1.setText("");
                for(int J=0;J<hide.length()-1;J++)
                {    
                    text1.setText(text1.getText()+hide.charAt(J));
                }
                text1.setText(text1.getText()+buttonNumber);
            }
        }
    }else
    {
        String txt4 = text1.getText();
        int len = txt4.length();
        String ss = txt4.substring(len-2);
        System.out.println("ss "+ss);

        if(ss.equals("+0") || ss.equals("-0") || ss.equals("*0") || ss.equals("/0"))
        {
            String hide=text1.getText();
            text1.setText("");
            for(int J=0;J<hide.length()-1;J++)
            {    
                text1.setText(text1.getText()+hide.charAt(J));
            }
            text1.setText(text1.getText()+buttonNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            String txt5 = text1.getText();
            boolean endwith3 = txt5.endsWith(")");

            if(true!=endwith3)
            { 
                if(numbcount1<=5)
                {   
                    text1.setText(text1.getText()+buttonNumber);
                    numbcount1++;
                }
                dotcheck=true;
                baketsub=false;

                String txt6 = text1.getText();
                int le = txt6.length();
                int subt = le-numbcount1;
                String subs1 = txt6.substring(subt);
                System.out.println("tt"+subt);
                System.out.println("tt"+subs1);
                check1 = subs1.contains(".");
                System.out.println("tt"+check1);    
                check=false;
            }
        }
    }
    baketcheck=false;  

    String txt = text1.getText();
    int ff = txt.length();
    System.out.print("ffss"+ff);
    if(ff>=14)
    {
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrib, 25);
    text1.setParagraphAttributes(attrib, true);
        if(ff>=25)
        {
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrib, 20);
            text1.setParagraphAttributes(attrib, true);
        }
    }
}

private void dots(String dot) 
{   
    String txt7 = text1.getText();
    boolean endwith4 = txt7.endsWith(dot);

    if(true == dotcheck)
    {
        if(check==false && check1==false)
        {
            if(false==endwith4)
            {
                text1.setText(text1.getText()+dot);
            }
        }
    } 
} 

public  void total()
{
    try
    {    
        Object result = engine.eval(text1.getText());

        if(result==null)
        {
            text1.setText("Wrong null");
        }else
        {
            text1.setText("\n ="+result.toString()); 
        }
    }
    catch(ScriptException es)
    {
        text1.setText("Wrong format");
    }
} 

private void cancel1() {

    if(!text1.getText().equals(""))   
    {
        String txt8  = text1.getText();
        boolean endwith5 = txt8.endsWith("(");
        if(true==endwith5)
        {
            String hide=text1.getText();
            text1.setText("");
            for(int J=0;J<hide.length()-1;J++)
            {
                text1.setText(text1.getText()+hide.charAt(J));
            }
            baketcount--; 
            baketcount1=1;

            baketsub=true;
        }else
        {
            String txt9 = text1.getText();
            int length = txt9.length();
            String subs2 = txt9.substring(length-1);
            System.out.println(subs2);
            if(subs2.equals("+") || subs2.equals("-") ||subs2.equals("/")  || subs2.equals("-") )
            {
                String hide=text1.getText();
                text1.setText("");
                for(int J=0;J<hide.length()-1;J++)
                {
                    text1.setText(text1.getText()+hide.charAt(J));
                }
                opercount--;
            }else
            {
                if(length<=lensold)
                {    
                    String hide=text1.getText();
                    text1.setText("");
                    for(int J=0;J<hide.length()-1;J++)
                    {
                        text1.setText(text1.getText()+hide.charAt(J));
                    }
                    numbcount--; 
                    operaffer=true;
                    baketsub=true;
                    baketcheck=true;
                }else
                {
                    String hide=text1.getText();
                    text1.setText("");
                    for(int J=0;J<hide.length()-1;J++)
                    {
                        text1.setText(text1.getText()+hide.charAt(J));
                    }
                    numbcount1--;
                }    
            }
        }

        String txt = text1.getText();
        int ff = txt.length();
        System.out.print("ffss"+ff);
        if(ff<=14)
        {
            StyleConstants.setFontSize(attrib, 30);
            text1.setParagraphAttributes(attrib, true);
        }
    }      
}

private void Baket() 
{
    if(baketcheck==true)
    {
        text1.setText(text1.getText()+"(");
        baketcount++;
    }else
    {
        if(baketcount1<=baketcount)
        {    
            text1.setText(text1.getText()+")");
            baketcount1++;
        }else
        {
            text1.setText(text1.getText()+"*");
            baketcheck=true;
            operaffer=false;
            numbcount1=1;
            opercount++;
        }
    }    
    System.out.print(baketcount);
}

private void baketsub() 
{
    if(text1.getText().equals(""))
    {
        if(baketsub==true)
        {
        text1.setText(text1.getText()+"(-");
        }
        baketcheck=false;
        baketcount++;
        opercount++;
    }
}

private static class ScrollLookandFeel  extends BasicScrollBarUI {

     private ScrollLookandFeel() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void configureScrollBarColors() {

        thumbColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        thumbDarkShadowColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        thumbHighlightColor = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        thumbLightShadowColor = Color.lightGray;

        trackColor = new Color(245, 245, 245);
        trackHighlightColor = new Color(245, 245, 245);
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
        JButton button = new BasicArrowButton(orientation);
        button.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
        button.setForeground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
        button.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
        JButton button = new BasicArrowButton(orientation);
        button.setBackground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
        button.setForeground(new Color(245, 245, 245));
        button.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        return button;
    }
}

class WrapEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit
{
   final ViewFactory defaults = new WrapColumnFactory();

    @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory()
    {
        return defaults;
    }
}

class WrapColumnFactory implements ViewFactory
{
    @Override
    public View create(Element elem) {
       String ki = elem.getName();
       if(ki!=null)
       {
           switch (ki) {
               case AbstractDocument.ContentElementName:
                   return new WrapLabelView(elem);
               case AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName:
                   return new ParagraphView(elem);
               case AbstractDocument.SectionElementName:
                   return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
               case StyleConstants.ComponentElementName:
                   return new ComponentView(elem);
               case StyleConstants.IconElementName:
                   return new IconView(elem);
           }
       }
        return new LabelView(elem);
    }  
}

class WrapLabelView extends LabelView
{
    public WrapLabelView(Element elem) 
    {
       super(elem);
    }

    @Override
    public float getMinimumSpan(int axis)
    {
        switch (axis)
        {
            case View.X_AXIS:
                return 0;
            case View.Y_AXIS:
                return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid axis"+axis);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String []args)
{
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
}  
}
```